# onPostExecute Looper AsyncTask

Tags: java, android

My Android application allows users to update their Facebook status from a Fragment. I've implemented the following AsyncTask so they can log in:

```
    public class updateFacebookTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... message) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Async UFT");

        myFResult = false;

            Looper.prepare();   

            if (loginAndPostToWall()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "loginAndPostToWall Returned: " + myFResult);

                myFResult = true;

            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "loginAndPostToWall Returned: " + myFResult);

                myFResult = false;
            }


            //Looper.loop();


        return myFResult;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        Log.i(TAG, "UFT - oPrE");

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean myFResult) {
        super.onPostExecute(myFResult);

        if (myFResult) {
            Log.i(TAG, "UFT oPE - Success: " + myFResult);


        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "UFT oPE - fail: " + myFResult);

        }
    }
```

The AsyncTask uses the method loginAndPostToWall() as below, Which implements a DialogListener as part of the Facebook sdk:

```
public boolean loginAndPostToWall() {

    myFResult = false;

    facebook.authorize(getActivity(), PERMISSIONS,
            Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new DialogListener() {

                public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "LoginDialog Complete - Success");


                    myFResult = true;


                }

                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
                    Log.w(TAG,
                            "onFacebookError - Authentication with Facebook failed");


                    myFResult = false;

                }

                public void onError(DialogError error) {
                    Log.w(TAG,
                            "onError - Authentication with Facebook failed");
                    looper = false;
                    Log.i(TAG, "looper " + looper);

                    myFResult = false;

                }

                public void onCancel() {
                    Log.w(TAG,
                            "onCancel - Authentication with Facebook cancelled");


                    myFResult = false;

                }
            });


    return myFResult;
}
```

I have two problems that I really need help with please:

1. LogInAndPostToWall immediately returns myFResult as false. What I want it to do is wait until the login by webView has returned onComplete (or an error) from the DialogListener. How can I get it to return myFResult at that point and not before?
2. If I include Looper.loop(); onPostExecute is never called. If I don't include Looper.prepare(); I get an error saying I can't create a handler without it. Am I supposed to call quit() somewhere?

I've been stuck on this for two days (!) and have read many, many SO posts - I've tried using runnables and logging which threads everything is running on etc, but no joy.

Thanks in advance for saving me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

loginAndPostToWall() should be executed on the UI thread, as it modifyes the UI. doInBackgorund() method got never executed on UI thread and you should NOT ever include Looper.prepare() or Looper.loop() code there.

Comment: I originally had loginAndPostToWall on the UI thread, but it would FC because I was running it there with http functions - I had to use the StrictMode workaround to prevent that, but assumed Async was the correct method?

Comment: i think you can use a handler to post, even in doinbackground. as long as the handler is attached to the ui thread.

Comment: @Vladimir - I've just stripped my code and run loginAndPostToWall on the UI thread. It didn't force close. I'm totally baffled... It definitely used to! Unbelievable... Anyway, I'll run it on some other devices to check and return to mark your answer as correct. Any ideas on returning myFResult once onComplete has returned would be appreciated. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @DhruvGairola I tried with the handlers but it wouldn't attach correctly. I think Vladimir has put me right though. Thanks.